# Setting specific day on date field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to set coming Thursday on my SharePoint date field as default date.For example whenever I open the form it should display coming Thursday as default date in  Any idea what will be the formula ?

Comment: provide more detail about your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default value to be "next Thursday", then 
a) if today is Thursday and you want the default date to be today:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Today]<5),[Today]+4-WEEKDAY([Today]),[Today]+11-WEEKDAY([Today]))
```

b) if today is Thursday and you want the default date to be next Thursday, not today:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Today]<4),[Today]+4-WEEKDAY([Today]),[Today]+11-WEEKDAY([Today]))
```

If today is not Thursday, you get "next Thursday" as expected in both cases.